# How to rdp into a pc that is on USB tethering?

Tags: remote-desktop, tethering

I have a pc1 and a phone that are connected to a router/internet.
I have a pc2 that is using the above phone to get internet using USB tethering.

The pc2 ip is 192.169.42.234, which doesn't match the network 192.168.1.x

I would like to rdp from pc2 into pc1, how can I do that?

Comment: Although the question is a bit old, you can find your way in https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/28530

Comment: Thanks. The app I found below made it much easier to do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it very easily using app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elixsr.portforwarder&hl=en_GB

```
port forwarding 
from 
wlan0:3389
to 
192.168.42.234:3389
```

You pc ip might be different, you can check it by running ipconfig in a command prompt (cmd)